# Why would opening a database with DAO first making access with ODBC or OleDB much faster?

Tags: sql, ms-access, odbc, oledb, dao

I have been following [this tutorial on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ado-net-code-examples) to access the sample Northwind Access 97 and Access 2000 databases.

The code is mostly from the tutorial and relatively complex to re-create here, but my question is easy to state. Opening and closing the database first with DAO speeds up subsequent access using ODBC and OleDB by ~20-fold...why?

Test 1: Repeatedly run (200 times) the following SQL query against the Access 97 and Access 2000 databases, reading all records in the returned data:

```
"SELECT ProductID, UnitPrice, ProductName FROM Products " +
"WHERE UnitPrice > ? " +
"ORDER BY UnitPrice DESC;"
```

Results (ODBC) 1:

- Access 97: 200 cycles, reading 75 records per cycle took 22875ms
- Access 2000: 200 cycles, reading 75 records per cycle took 12125ms

Results (OleDb) 1:

- Access 97: 200 cycles, reading 75 records per cycle took 21656ms
- Access 2000: 200 cycles, reading 75 records per cycle took 11578ms

Now make the following change to the code:

```
private void OpenDbWithDAO(string strDatabase)
{
    // Dummy open and close the target database...
    DAO.DBEngine dbEngine = new DAO.DBEngine();
    DAO.Database db = dbEngine.OpenDatabase(strDatabase, false, false);
    db.Close();
    // This consumes ~15ms for each database opened
}
```

Test 2: Exactly the same as test 1, except first call OpenDbWithDAO(PATH).

Results (ODBC) 2:

- Access 97: 200 cycles, reading 75 records per cycle took 922ms
- Access 2000: 200 cycles, reading 75 records per cycle took 610ms

Results (OleDb) 2:

- Access 97: 200 cycles, reading 75 records per cycle took 625ms
- Access 2000: 200 cycles, reading 75 records per cycle took 390ms

Is this normal?

#### UPDATE

Added timing for the dummy open/close of the database. For both the Access 97 and 2000 databases, the time to open/close the databases is ~30ms.

Comment: Not sure, but Windows will use free RAM to buffer files. So it may be as simple as opening the file via DAO caused it to buffer to RAM before the benchmarks.

Comment: Do your results account for the time required to do the initial `dbEngine.OpenDatabase()`?

Comment: @GordThompson: No, good point. What I can say is that the Open database call is fast (under 1s), but I will get exact timing info and update the question. The idea from Joel about caching, whether in the Windows file system or (more likely) in the database/database engine seems more likely.

Comment: @GordThompson: Timing information added. The initial `dbEngine.OpenDatabase` and `db.Close` calls consume around 15ms.

Comment: I am able to reproduce your issue. For me the difference is not 20x but still significant. Using ODBC, 200 iterations without the dummy DAO open takes about 12 seconds, whereas with the dummy DAO open it takes more like 5 seconds. I honestly have no idea why that might be.

Comment: Further testing indicates that the dummy DAO open affects the time required to *open* an ODBC connection. Moving the `new OdbcConnection()` out of the loop (instead of opening a new connection each time) reduces the execution time dramatically and the case with the dummy DAO open actually comes out a bit slower (1000 ms with, 800 ms without).